# What is the memory before 7c00H used for?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, bootloader, microprocessors

If the code for bootloader is stored from memory adrress 0x7c00, then what is stored in the preceding memory and what is it used for?

I have just started learning about assembly and bootloader and found we use [ORG 0x7c00] as our code will be stored starting from this address. Now in some tutorials on youtube they also put this address inside bp and sp, so is this space used for storing temporary data and holding return address after a function is called using stack? I was a bit confused because not everyone in these tutorials use these stack pointers and even some don't use this address for bp and sp instead use a location higher than 7c00.

Comment: Memory from `00000h` to `003ffh` is used for the the interrupt vector table, `00400h` to `004ffh` is the BIOS data area and everything after that is free for use.  The BIOS loads your bootloader to `7c00h` because that is the last address guaranteed to be available even on an original IBM PC with 32 kB memory, allowing the boot loader to load a kernel to address `00600h` or similar.  There are some PC memory maps on the internet.  Check them out!

Answer (score 0):

Memory organization as follow:

from 0x00 to 0x03FF -> Real mode interrupt vector table

from 0x0400 to 0x04FF -> BIOS data area

from 0x0500 to 0x7BFF -> unused

from 0x7C00 to 0x7DFF -> Boot sector in RAM

from 0x7E00 to 0x09_FFFF -> unused

from 0x0A_0000 to 0x0A_FFFF -> Colour Video RAM (VRAM)

from 0x0B_0000 to 0x0B_7FFF -> Monocrome VRAM

from 0x0B_8000 to 0x0B_FFFF -> Video Text RAM

from 0x0C_000 to 0x0C_7FFF -> Video ROM BIOS

from 0x0C_8000 to 0x0E_FFFF -> BIOS shadow area

from 0x0F_0000 to 0x0F_FFFF -> System BIOS

The Boot Sector in RAM at 0x7C00 divides the RAM into two regions. When I developed my bootloader, I used the RAM region from 0x500 to 0x7BFF as working RAM to place the stack, local variables etc. I used the remaining unused RAM region to load the binary file from the Hard Disk.
The binary file can be anything, but typically this is the so-called second stage in the boot process.

You can read all the details about how I developed my bootloader at:
https://fromthegroundupmyway.blogspot.com/2020/10/design-and-build-space-shuttle.html